# How do I check for multiple elements in an array - Warning Homework

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I cant figure out a condition that could check for all 6 numbers.  I tried using || but its just messy and i know thats not correct.

Using the following Array, create variable called numThrees with the value [13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73]

```
var numArray = [13, 15, 17, 23, 25, 27, 33, 35, 37, 43, 45, 47, 53, 55, 57, 63, 65, 67, 73, 75, 77];

var numThrees = [];

for (i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
    if (numArray[i] ===  13) {
    numThrees[i] = numArray[i];
    };
  };
 document.getElementById('q7').innerHTML = numThrees;
```

Comment: It is customary to up vote helpful answers and to mark the one that best answers your question as the answer. We typically bristle at doing homework.

Answer (score 0):

you can just check if the remainder of the number with 10 is 3 ,which is for your condition(13,23,33,43,53,63 and 73)

```js
var numArray = [13, 15, 17, 23, 25, 27, 33, 35, 37, 43, 45, 47, 53, 55, 57, 63, 65, 67, 73, 75, 77];

var numThrees = [];

for (i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
  if (numArray[i]%10==3) {
    numThrees.push(numArray[i]);
  };
};
document.getElementById('q7').innerHTML = numThrees;
```

```html
<div id="q7">
  </div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Here are two that use different logic to extract the right numbers:

**You can do this the manual way:**

```js
var numArray = [13, 15, 17, 23, 25, 27, 33, 35, 37, 43, 45, 47, 53, 55, 57, 63, 65, 67, 73, 75, 77];

var numThrees = [];

for(var i = 0; i < numArray.length; ++i){
 
  // Turn the current array element into a string
  var strVal = numArray[i].toString();
  
  // If that string ends with "3" add it to the new array:
  strVal[strVal.length-1] === "3" ? numThrees.push(numArray[i]) : "";
}

console.log(numThrees);
```

**You can use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:**

```js
var numArray = [13, 15, 17, 23, 25, 27, 33, 35, 37, 43, 45, 47, 53, 55, 57, 63, 65, 67, 73, 75, 77];

// The Array.prototype.filter method iterates every item in
// a given array and allows you to implement any logic you
// like and return any value from the original array you like
// into a new array that will be a filter of the first one.
var numThrees = numArray.filter(function(element){
  // Check the current element being iterated for one of 
  // a designated set of values and return that element
  // into the filtered array if it is a match.
  switch(element){
    case 13:
    case 23:
    case 33:
    case 43:
    case 53:
    case 63:
    case 73:
      return element;
    default:
      break;
  }
});

console.log(numThrees);
```

Comment: A down vote for two correct answers with references?!

Answer (score 0):

Your instructions are a bit arbitrary, but here's a more efficient way of doing it:

```
var numArray = [13, 15, 17, 23, 25, 27, 33, 35, 37, 43, 45, 47, 53, 55, 57, 63, 65, 67, 73, 75, 77];

var numThrees = [];

for (i = 0; i < numArray.length; i+=3) {
    numThrees.push(numArray[i]);
};
document.getElementById('q7').innerHTML = numThrees;
```

Since we can observe that the given array has the desired values at certain indices which are equally spaced apart, there's no need to iterate through the entire array.

Your directions don't specify if we can do it based on the assumption that we know what's in the original array and what index. If this is the case, then you do need to iterate through the array in some fashion, and then test to see if each index contains your desired value.

I'm assuming this is an acceptable solution.

Edit: Based on my understanding (and likely what's more efficient.) I don't think that, in this case, we should be iterating through the entire array when its hard coded. We know what values are in the array, and at what position. It just so happens that the numbers you want are evenly spaced in the numArray, which is even more reason to not test each value to some condition.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need items ending in 3, or every third item in the array??

Using Array.filter is the most efficent way to achieve either by:

returning values with a remainder of 3 when divisible by 10.

```js
var numArray = [13, 15, 17, 23, 25, 27, 33, 35, 37, 43, 45, 47, 53, 55, 57, 63, 65, 67, 73, 75, 77];

var numThrees = numArray.filter(function(val){
 return val % 10 === 3;
});

console.log(numThrees);
```

If however, you need get every third element in the array you can do the following which returns the item if the iterator has no remainder when divided by 3

```js
var numArray = [13, 15, 17, 23, 25, 27, 33, 35, 37, 43, 45, 47, 53, 55, 57, 63, 65, 67, 73, 75, 77];

var numThrees = numArray.filter(function(val, i) {
 return i % 3 === 0;
});

console.log(numThrees);
```

Answer (score -2):

Convert the array to list and use `Contains`

```
var list = numArray.ToList();
if (list.Contains(thing))
 ...
```

Comment: The question is tagged Javascript, not C#.